# update images on fan page which update wordpress website

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Hi is it possible to have a plugin/development feature where if i update images on my fan page the wordpress website gallery section updates automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to write a plugin if Wordpress offers some sort of API (I don't know Wordpress..but here's a linkn to their APIs http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_API%27s).  You should start here with learning the Graph API (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and how to post images to a page's album. From there once you get that working, then figure out how to also cross post those images to Wordpress via their API.